# Is it possible to use the speaker on programmatically initiated phone calls?

Tags: iphone, phone-call

I'm using the following iPhone SDK code to initiate a phone call programmatically:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"12345678"]];
```

The call is initiated just fine, my question is if it's possible to programmatically set the speaker as the audio source for this initiated phone call?

What I'm trying to achieve is that the call will be initiated and automatically use the iPhone speaker as the call audio source.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. You can only initiate calls using the method you described but you can't do anything else without private api.

Comment: its been 5 years, still we cant access it?