# Make a phone call using speakerphone programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an application that initiates a phone call to a predetermined number. I would like to use the speakerphone for this but can't find the method to turn on the speaker anywhere but within an audio player. I'm using UIApplication.sharedApplication to initiate the phone call. Any help turning on the speaker would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This looks like a similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27246539/enable-and-disable-speaker-in-xcode-ios-8-1-while-calling

Comment: This is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4545395/1346426