# Can we enable/disable Call Audio Routing setting in ios programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, audio-route

I'm starting a call in `ios` programmatically like this:

```
NSString *telString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", @"9898989898",];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:telString]];
```

Along with this, I want to enable speaker automatically for this phone call from my app as per client request. I know user can do it mannualy like following:

[image]

Can we access this **Call Audio Routing** setting from our app? or is there other possibility?

[Referring to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545395/is-it-possible-to-use-the-speaker-on-programmatically-initiated-phone-calls) its not possible, but have things changed in these 5 years?